# MYSQL процедура сравнения данных с переменными и запись в другую таблицу

Tags: mysql

С процедурами совсем не бум-бум. Писал все обычными запросами но в некоторых случаях приходилось делать 2-3-4 запроса чтоб получить итоговый вариант. Решил перейти на процедуры...

Погуглил, почекал, в итоге подобного варианта не нашел...

Цель получить все данные `_email`, `_password` и тд.
после чего найти запись в таблице `users` которая равна `users.email = _email AND users.password = _password` после чего из этой записи получить `id` и записать переменные `_token, _expires_at, _code, user_id( id из таблицы users )` в таблицу preToken

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `getPreliminaryToken` 
(
IN _email VARCHAR(45),
IN _password VARCHAR(45),
IN _token VARCHAR(45),
IN _expires_at DATETIME,
IN _code INT
)
BEGIN
 ***
END
```

без процедуры я выполняю :

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?`

проверяю пароли и тд в коде программы и делаю запрос на добавление новой записи:

`REPLACE INTO preToken (token, expires_at, user_id, code) values(?, ?, ?, ?);`

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: так сделайте просто одним запросом, зачем вам процедура?

Comment: между запросами есть обработка данных. Если эти проверки перенести в процедуру то можно обойтись 1 запросом

Comment: вот очень просто для начала

Comment: сделал одним запросом но все же оставил в процедуре так как меньше мусора в коде программы

Comment: Сложный вопрос. Я сделал проект на процедурах и триггерах, клиент переехал на другой хостинг, там все запрещено )

Comment: в данном случае я использую VPS хостинг и подобных ограничений у меня нет. Ну если станет подобный вопрос то уже буду думать . на данный момент, во время разработки, процедуры избавляют функции от овербольших размеров. Из за нескольких запросов подряд + строки самих запросов занимают очень много.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем сделал процедуру: ( можно выполнить просто запросом но процедура проще в использовании)

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `getPreliminaryToken` 
(
IN _email VARCHAR(45),
IN _password VARCHAR(45),
IN _token VARCHAR(100),
IN _expires_at DATETIME,
IN _code INT
)
BEGIN
REPLACE INTO `pretoken` (token, expires_at, user_id, code)
SELECT _token, _expires_at, id, _code
FROM users
WHERE  users.email = _email AND users.password = _password;
END
```